# WebIDE can't connect to remote runtime on adb-connected device

Tags: web-ide

From WebIDE (Windows 10 x64, Android SDK 26, Firefox 56 ESR) I'm trying to connect to my Huawei 7A Pro (USB debugging enabled, adb-connected, showing serial). Doing everything exactly according to this manual:
https://sites.google.com/view/bananahackers/development/webide
After executing this adb command
c:/>adb forward tcp:6000 localfilesystem:/data/local/debugger-socket
should get listening port as output but I get non (no errors either). I suppose port is not forwarded at this point and it causes futher connecting issue.
When I enter Firefox WebIDE it doesn't see my device, on pressing Remote Runrime button I get the following error:
Operation failed: Connecting to Remote Runtime. Though I can connect to Remote Firefox on my drvice.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas on how to fix connection issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realised the method  with WebIDE to call runrime is for KaiOS devices only. On Android you could debug Firefox with WebIDE addon installed only